# When should one use \begingroup instead of \bgroup?

Tags: tex-core, best-practices, grouping, implicit-braces

Is there ever a case when the use of `\begingroup` is preferred to `\bgroup`? Obviously, `\bgroup` is necessary in cases where you need to have balanced braces and thus cannot use `{`, but when is it necessary to use `\begingroup`?

A related question would be: What's the difference between a simple group and a semi-simple group?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`\bgroup` is a synonym for `{`, which is defined in Plain TeX using `\let\bgroup={`.

It interacts with TeX's "digestive system" in hairy ways: `{`s and `\bgroup`s start the same sort of groups, called simple groups, and each can be terminated with either `}`s or `\egroup`s, since they are the same.  But when the TeX digestive system encounters them, they are of different catcodes, so commands that look ahead, e.g., in LaTeX with `\section\bgroup Title}`, can break this matching.

`\begingroup` is different.  It is a TeX primitive, and it matches a different sort of group that TeX accounts for separately, called "semi-simple groups" (a Knuth joke, I assume).  Thus a `\begingroup` must be terminated by an `\endgroup`, not a `}`, and vice versa for `\endgroup`.

I generally avoid `\bgroup`, and use `\begingroup`, but `\bgroup` could be useful if you are messing about with a nested token list.

Comment: `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` also behaves differently in math mode, in which `{`...`}` or `\bgroup`...`\egroup` create a subformulae with different spacing. A good rule of thumb would be to avoid using `\bgroup`...`\egroup` unless you know you need them.

Comment: I don't know exactly how they behave so my preference goes this way use {} when it works, otherwise \begingroup \endgroup.

Comment: Will is right: I'd strongly favour `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup`.

Comment: Charles, thanks for the answer. Do you have a reference for the term "semi-simple group"? I can't locate any occurrence of it in the TeXbook...

Comment: @Jubobs (been away from SO&co for a while) - It's defined in the source and sort of documented in *TeX the Program*.  The Pascal declaration is given `define semi_simple_group = 14   {code for '\begingroup...\endgroup'}`.  In e-Tex, the \tracingmacros command allows you to see the semi-simple groups being called such as you enter and exit them during expansion.

Comment: Apart from Will Robertson comment, the answer is a little vague (or may be I don't understand). You only said that they are different, but not really the *reasons* why it is, and the *consequences* it has to use one or other in different occasions (where the difference is relevant). Could you expand your answer a little bit?

Comment: @Manuel I think that adding some examples would be the right way to communicate the differences.  I'll add something in due course.

Comment: @LeoLiu Yes indeed. `{}` always go first, and if they don't work we should try `\begingroup ... \endgroup`. Only in cases that we may need unbalanced braces, such as define a new environment, should we use `\bgroup ... \egroup`.

Answer (score 38):

I have a little bit different opinion about `\bgroup` versus `\begingroup` than the previous answer. First, I give a short explanation about TeX internals:

The `{` and `}` (more exactly the tokens with catcode 1 and 2) have four different meanings in TeX:

- they are the syntactic part of macro definitions: `\def\foo...{...}`
- each sequence of tokens scanned as single token list in TeX (i.e. in the parameter of a macro, inside macro definitions...) have to be balanced text by these tokens: `\macro{param{e}ter}`.
- they are a part of several TeX primitive constructions, for example `\hbox...{...}`, `$e^{...}$`, `\write...{...}`.
- when they are used without any context mentioned above they open and close the group.

The `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are declared by `\let\bgroup={ \let\egroup=}` and you can replace `{` and `}` by `\bgroup` and `\egroup` only in the third and fourth meaning mentioned above. For example:

```
\hbox ... \bgroup ...}
\hbox ... {...\egroup
\hbox ... \bgroup ...\egroup
$e^\bgroup ...}$, $e^\bgroup...\egroup$
\write ...\bgroup ...}
```

The last line in the example is another exception: you canot replace the closing brace by `\egroup` if the syntactic rule `<general text>` (like in `\write` parameter) is applied.

The `\bgroup` and `\egroup` without the context mentioned in the third meaning above open and close a group. *The same work* do primitive commands `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` but only this work. They cannot be used instead of `{` and `}` in the first to third meaning mentioned above.

This means that always you can use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, it is possible to use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` with the same effect. But the nested groups have to be terminated by the appropriate counterpart, they cannot be crossed. And in math mode, there is a little bit different behavior, see comments.

I am preferring `\bgroup` and `\egroup` instead `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. Only, if I see that the nested group crossing error would be usable for users of my macros then I use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

Comment: Not the same effect: `\begingroup...\endgroup` and `{...}` in math mode give different results.

Comment: Of course, because `{...}` used in math mode is used in the third type of meanings mentioned above not the fourth. I.e they consists the math subformula. They begins and ends the group in math mode as a side effect, `\hbox` does the same side effect.

Comment: You say “whereever you can use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` it is possible to use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` with the same effect”, which is not true. `;-)`

Comment: To sum up, the only feature of using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` at all in TeX is their “transparency” in math mode. I had always thought they where something more (say more important, more relevant, more useful…).