# paralist: how to format the counter

Tags: lists, formatting, paralist

I use the following code to obtain a listed item

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{inparaenum}[(a)]
\item first item,
\item second item,
\item last item
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the counters, in this case: `(a), (b), (c)` to be formatted in bold (`\bfseries`). However, only the counter itself and not the surrounding parentheses should be in bold.

obviously the following doesnt work:

```
\begin{inparenum}[\bfseries{(a)}]
```

So can I achieve what I want without hardcoding the package?

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that `\bfseries` is not a macro that takes an argument; (that command is `\textbf{}`) it's a switch that "turns on" boldface.   Your posted answer also doesn't work, but lockstep's does for this reason: you need to turn boldface on inside the paretheses and then turn it off again, which is exactly what his solution does.

Comment: And you should accept egreg's answer, instead of lockstep's for the reasons stated... (This is one reason why it's a good idea to wait some time before accepting an answer.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "right" answer is

```
\begin{inparaenum}[(\bgroup\bfseries a\egroup)]
```

Calling `\normalfont` after `a` is not really a solution, as this might give a closing parenthesis different from the opening one (if the current font is slanted, for example).

Comment: @WillRobertson and @JosephWright concluded in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1932/16940 that `\begingroup` is usually preferable to `\bgroup`, but that there are situations where the latter has to be used. Does it make a difference here or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: @anonymous In this case it doesn't make any difference; what's important is not using `{...}` that would defeat the search for the `a` that states how to number the items.

Comment: Ah, now I got it: `\**b**group` stands for **begin**-group and `\**e**group` for *end*-group! Why didn't I realise before...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{inparaenum}[(\bfseries a\normalfont)]
\item first item,
\item second item,
\item last item
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the following achieves exactly what i wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{inparaenum}[\bfseries{} (a)]
\item first item,
\item second item,
\item last item
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't -- both parentheses are still bold in your example. Add `\normalfont` before the closing parenthesis, compile and compare.

Comment: This doesn't do what you want.

Comment: hmm.. it's very hard to see with the demifont i'm using but it appears you're right.