# Multiline comment

Tags: comments

In tex there is a way to do a comment multiline like in C, C++ `/* comment */` or in HTML `<!-- comment -->`? I'm currently using `\ifx`

```
\ifx true false
My multiline comment
that will not be in the
output pdf
\fi
```

but this may create a problem if I put inside the comment something like `\someundefcommand`.
I wish something like the standard `%` comment so I can put inside the comment I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Commenting out large sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/3323)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use the [`verbatim`](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
some comment
\someundefinedcommand
\end{comment}
a
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm. Why does `verbatim` provide this? I would expect to find it in its own package. Did the functionality fall out as a natural by-product of `verbatim`'s implementation?

Comment: Is it possible to define the `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` environment markers in terms of a character sequences - similarly to how the curly braces [are defined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1932/85504)?

Comment: should there be new line after `\begin{comment}` ?

Answer (score 58):

Instead `\ifx true false` you may use the shorter

```
\iffalse
dsaads
fdfdfds
\fi
```

If you ever want to have to 'activate' your comments later, you may define your own if:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifcomment
%\commenttrue # Show comments
\begin{document}

b

\ifcomment
dsaads
fdfdfds
\fi

a
\end{document}
```

But I would not recommend the `\ifcomment`. There are packages for this (the already mentioned [verbatim](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) or [comment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) or [version](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/version) or [versions](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/versions)).

Another interesting approach could be [todonotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes). Just don't show the todos. If you need them, you may define, where you get them (margin, footnote, own pages...)

Answer (score 24):

A similar solution I came up with is to define a `\comment` command:

```
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
```

The command makes LaTeX ignore anything inside.  This solution has the advantage over the other solutions (for me) of being a command rather than an environment with `\begin`/`\end` commands.

Usage:

```
Text that will be in the final document.
\comment{I am thinking of including this text,
but I don't want it in the compiled document right now.}
More text.
```

This can be modified à la @knut's answer to have an option for toggling the inclusion of the comments in the final document:

```
\newif\ifcomment
\commenttrue % Show comments
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\ifcomment#1\fi}
```

Comment: you can also use a delimited macro: `\long\def\comment #1\endcomment{}`. And as an alternative to using an `\if`, a companion command `\newcommand\showcomments{\let\comment\empty\let\endcomment\empty}`. The comment text should not be braced then to not create a group if the comments are to be shown. However, if the need arise to comment a whole block already containing commented out material, then do `\comment{...the whole thing...}\endcomment`.

Comment: I really like this idea. Because it makes it easier to clean your documents once your ready to submit. Simply comment out the command and see where it crashes. I do this for my `todo`'s