# Synctex and Environments

Tags: environments, forward-inverse-search

Synctex makes it possible to jump between your LaTeX code and the compiled PDF, which is absolutely great, if you have larger documents. However it is my impression that when you use environments, Synctex jumps only to the environment rather than the precise location you want to jump. This does not matter, if your environments are small, but it is very annoying, if your environments are large. Is there any way around this problem, e.g. changing the implementation of the environment or reconfiguring synctex etc.?

This questions is a result of discussion [Comment Multi-line Text on Counter Condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46973/comment-multi-line-text-on-counter-condition), because the result of this dicussion is an environment that typically includes large quantities of text.

This question might be similar to [SyncTeX functionality in TeXShop and TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50078/synctex-functionality-in-texshop-and-texworks), but I am not specifically interested in TeXShop.

Comment: @student: My mistake. -- Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39678/forward-inverse-search-using-synctex-with-the-precison-of-a-single-word

Comment: @Meneldur , You can try including more labels , subsections,  citations  so that  inverse search becomes more precise instead of showing the whole section. With Texmaker and Texworks, you can do Forward search using structure tags on the left window to the PDF on the right window. Similarly Inverse search can be done using the PDF Bookmarks/table of contents back to .tex source.

Comment: This can be fixed (LuaTeX only) if the feature is appropriately implemented: [luatex - How can I capture and rescan TeX source code while preserving synctex data? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631887/how-can-i-capture-and-rescan-tex-source-code-while-preserving-synctex-data/632368)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question here: [Is there a change to get SyncTeX work with text within environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571581/123626)

The thing is that `Environ` has the problem that within an environment generated by `\NewEnviron` the `\BODY` will only recognized as one block by SyncTeX.

But in environments created with `\newenvironment` the text within the environment is recognized by SyncTeX.
Nevertheless, as also stated in [SyncTeX functionality in TeXShop and TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50078/123626), SyncTeX recognizes only lines. So you have to use line breaks in you editor to get an appropriate resolution with SyncTeX.

If we takt the example from [Comment Multi-line Text on Counter Condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46973/123626), we get the folowing:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcounter{rlpublvl}%   %this counter stores the publication level
\newcommand{\rlstetpublvl}[1]{\setcounter{rlpublvl}{#1}}%    %sets the publication level to #1

\newenvironment{rltext}{}{}%
  
\newcommand{\rlcheckstatus}[1]{%    %activates the environment rltext if #1 >= rlpublvl
    \addtocounter{rlpublvl}{-1}%
    \ifthenelse{#1 > \value{rlpublvl}}%
        {\includecomment{rltext}}%
        {\excludecomment{rltext}} %
    \addtocounter{rlpublvl}{1}%
}%

\newif\ifhide
\hidefalse
\newenvironment{rlctxt}[1]{%
    \addtocounter{rlpublvl}{-1}%
    \ifthenelse{#1 > \value{rlpublvl}}%
        {}%
        {\hidetrue\expandafter\comment} %
}%
{%
\ifhide
   \endcomment\hidefalse
\fi
\addtocounter{rlpublvl}{1}%
}%


\begin{document}

\rlstetpublvl{5}    %global publication level set to 5

\rlcheckstatus{5} %this is printed
\begin{rltext}
This is ready
for publication.
\end{rltext}

\rlcheckstatus{0}  %this is not printed
\begin{rltext}
This part is still under construction.
\end{rltext}

%-------

\begin{rlctxt}{5}%  %this is printed
This is ready
for publication.
\end{rlctxt}

\begin{rlctxt}{0}%  %this is not printed
This part is still under construction.
\end{rlctxt}
\end{document}
```

Now `rlctxt` works with SyncTex as expected line-by-line with the text within the environment. `rltext` does not work like this because text in environments from the `comment` package are again recognized as one block by SyncTeX.