# Synctex problem with exsheets package

Tags: forward-inverse-search, exsheets

If I use forward or backward synctex within the question environment of exsheets package it points out the whole exercise and not precisely the wanted line inside the environment.

This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
 Line 1\\
 Line 2
\end{question}

  Line 3
\end{document}
```

The synctex doesn't point out line1 or line2 in the question environment however it gives exactly the line3. Is this a bug in the exsheets package and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not bug, but missing feature. As for "how to fix" contact the author and ask nicely (not demand) them to implement it, or implement yourself and make a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By doing some more search, I figure out that this a missing feature for synctex and not for exsheets. link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50194/synctex-and-environments

Comment: Not really, there are workarounds. See the comment I recently added to linked question