# Is it possible to pagebreak aligned equations?

Tags: equations, page-breaking

The report I'm writting features a lot of long, multiple lines equations. To reduce visual polution I've been using an `aligned` environment nested inside `equation`. This way (unlike just using an `align` environment) I get only a single label for all the lines.

The problem is that so many long equations often need to be broken into two pages, otherwise I get lots of blank vertical space in the document. However the `aligned` environment does not allow the `\displaybreak` command.

**Is there an alternative way to achieve a pagebreak inside an aligned equation?**

*Here's a sample ofthe equations I'm using*

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    ...\\
    ...\\  %I need to pagebreak here
    ...\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
```

Comment: What about the `split` environment?

Comment: About `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}`: Would `\begin{align}...\notag \\  \label{where you want it} \\ \end{align}` (or the `split` environment as mentioned by Stephan Lehmke) be a possible alternative for you?

Comment: @Stephen I'll try it now, but according to AucTeX split can't be broken either. `align`+`\notag` seems like a good idea. I wasn't using it because that would involve managing dozens of `\notag`s. But I suppose I could use it only on the problematic equations.

Comment: if you only want one number you can use the starred form of the environment and use `\tag` once rather than the unstarred form and use `\notag` on all but one line

Answer (score 258, accepted):

In relation to the comments I want to answer this question.

First of all to allow page breaks inside equations you have to set the command `\allowdisplaybreaks`. Without setting this one no page break occurs.

Using a simple align-environment. Of course as @DavidCarlisle suggested you can use the star variant to suppress the numbering and set a specific tag by `\tag`.

The environment `split` can't handle page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\kant[1-3]
\begin{align*}
    a\\
    b\\
    c\\
    d\\
    e\tag{\stepcounter{equation}\theequation}\\
    f\\
    g\\
    h\\
    i
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `tag` thing is not working for me. I found this `\stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\label{myeq1}` working.

Comment: It somehow solves my problem of a mildly underfull split equation...it didn't break, but fudge the spaces a little bit...why...?

Comment: What's the correct way to set `\allowdisplaybreaks` locally? Just directly saying it inside a group surrounding the `align*`? Or inside the `align*`?

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102173/using-allowdisplaybreaks-locally-for-a-single-chapter-single-equation) - yes, using a `group` works

Comment: This is just one of the most useful and fundamental commands I've ever discovered and I am astonished by how many thousands of LaTeX lines of code I have already written without knowing it.

Comment: how can this be used for \begin{equation}\begin{aligned} XXX \end{aligned}\end{equation}

Comment: Optionally, to identify the second part of the page-broken equation, you can add `\tag{\theequation}` (that is, without `\stepcounter`) to some equation line; in the example above you could write `h\tag{\theequation}\\ `. So you will have the equation tag, for example, `(7.2)` on both pages; otherwise it might feel strange to see an equation chunk without numbering, even more if LaTeX sets some floats in between.

Answer (score 108):

Additionally to the above answers, as asked in comments, the command `\allowdisplaybreaks` from `amsmath` can be used **locally** do a display break by using the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` commands:

```
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}
    ....
\end{align}
\endgroup
```

Or simpler syntax (shoutout to [GWPR](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/262394/gpwr)):

```
{\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}
    ....
\end{align}
}
```

Comment: This answer indicates that without `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, the effect of `\allowdisplaybreaks` are applied globally.

Comment: Best answer, because it doesn't break the rest of the document. For example, I have a bunch of small equation systems which I did not want to break over pages. However, I also had a couple very long ones. This solution comes in handy because it avoids having to manually break pages before every single short equation system that one desires to keep together, because of the latter's small size.

Comment: @KaiserKatze *Globally* or everywhere *after* the instance of `\allowdisplaybreaks`?

Comment: Can `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` nor be replaced by `{` and `}`, respectively?

Comment: @GPWR Can confirm it does work. As another note, on a primitive level the `{` and `}` are not equivalent to `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/when-should-one-use-begingroup-instead-of-bgroup)

Answer (score 24):

Just add the `\allowdisplaybreaks` command from the `amsmath` package to the preamble of your document. Works only with the math environments provided by this package. So you can use `align`.

Comment: Isn't this all covered in the other answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B To be fair, the other answer doesn't clarify that this only works with the environments from `amsmath`, so that the solution doesn't work with, for example, a custom math environment. This answer does clarify that.

Comment: Also, the `\allowdisplaybreaks` command accepts an optional value of 1-4 indicating how "allowed" display breaks are. E.g., `\allowdisplaybreaks[4]` will allow more display breaks than `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` will.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting my version because it took me some time to figure that out and i hope it will help others also.

`\allowdisplaybreaks` goes before `\begin{document}` and it is used only once. Then a very general code example for an equation is the following

```latex
\begin{align} 
\sum{...a very large expression...} &= \sum{...another large expression...} \nonumber \\ 
&= \sum{...a result which is also large but needs to be aligned under first "="...} \nonumber \\
{...again a large expression...} &= {...still a large expression...}  \\
&= {... a final large expression...}
\end{align}
```

If `\nonumber` is not used, latex will assign numbers to every line break which for the majority of cases is useless. That worked for me

Comment: `align*` gives the not-numbered version. So, this answers is pointless.