# Using `\allowdisplaybreaks` locally for a single chapter / single equation

Tags: math-mode, page-breaking, amsmath

I do have a longer paper. In one chapter I got several multiline equations, which I wrote using the `align` environment from `amsmath`-package. Actually those are quite long computations which should break anywhere for avoiding to much empty space on a page.

I want to use something like `\allowdisplaybreaks`, which does exactly what I want. The problem is, that I do not want to allow displaybreaks anywhere else in the document, where I have no control about it. I tried to use `\allowdisplaybreaks` directly before `\begin{align}`, hoping it would only apply on the next following `align`-enviroment. But it applies to every `align`-environment later in the text.

Is there any way to "stop" the command again?

And yes, I could use `\displaybreak` for single breaks, but I had to use it in many equations and I needed to put it in every single line, since the pagebreak should move, if I add a few more lines anywhere in the chapter.

Thanks for your help,
Greyfox

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can localize the breaks if you code your display like this:

```
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align}
 ...
\end{align}%
\endgroup
```

the percent sign probably isn't needed after the `\end{align}`, but i'm just playing it safe, to avoid a possible space at the beginning of the next line if it doesn't start a new paragraph.

Comment: In such cases I'd be tempted to do `\begin{allowdisplaybreaks}\begin{align}...\end{align}\end{allowdisplaybreaks}`, but that's probably bad form.   —  EDIT (after reading implementation) it seems that `\allowdisplaybreaks[0]` should disable breaks again.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch -- i'll have to try that.  don't usually experiment with commands-turned-into-environments if they're not predefined.  also need to check on presence of space at beginning of text line after display.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch does the environment `\begin{allowdisplaybreaks}...\end{allowdisplaybreaks}` belong to any package or is it a standard LaTeX environment?

Comment: @Taekwondavide It's an ugly hack that I probably shouldn't have suggested: `\begin{anything}...\end{anything}` is roughly the same as `\begingroup\anything...\endanything\endgroup`, but works even if `\endanything` is not defined.