# An align environment for too many lines of equations

Tags: align

It seems that if I write too many lines of equation within an align environment after some text, that environment will not span more than one pages, and leave blank at the bottom half of the previous page. How can I make it span more than one pages? Thanks.

Comment: \Allowdisplaybreaks ?

Comment: Was just about to suggest `\allowdisplaybreaks` as cmhughes already did. See [this question/answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102173/21344) for a way to limit the setting to a particular display.

Comment: While `\allowdisplaybreaks` (maybe used locally as the answer to the duplicate question suggests) may seem handy, I think it's better to judiciously place `\displaybreak` after having examined the display for choosing the best break point.