# Combination of subequations and align environments leaves a lot of white space (sometimes)

Tags: align, subequations

The fragment of my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.5pt}
    \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.5pt}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\small\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{xxx}
    \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{xxx}
    \renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\mbeq}{\overset{!}{=}}

This is known as the \emph{Born rule} or Born's probabilistic interpretation \citep{BornRule}. If two additional observables $ \{ B, C \} $ are necessary to form a CSCO (see \ref{CSCO}), the projector onto the degenerate eigenspace associated with $ a' $ is given by:
\begin{subequations}
\label{EigenSpaceProjector}
\begin{align}
\hat{\Lambda}_{a'} & = \smashoperator{\sum_{%
  \substack{i, j \mid b_{i} \in \mathscr{B},\\ 
            \hfill c_{j} \in \mathscr{C}\phantom{,}}}} 
  \,\ket{a', b_{i}, c_{j}} \bra{a', b_{i}, c_{j}} \rightarrow \ket{a'} \bra{a'} \label{EigenSpaceProjectorDiscr} \\
\text{and} \quad \hat{\Lambda}_{a'} & = \int\limits_{\mathscr{B}} \! \diff b \int\limits_{\mathscr{C}} \! \diff c \, \ket{a', b, c} \bra{a', b, c} \rightarrow \ket{a'} \bra{a'} \, , \label{EigenSpaceProjectorCont}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
with the simpler form included if the eigenvalue $ a' $ is non-degenerate. The probability of the measurement returning any value at all has to equal unity in order for the probability interpretation \eqref{BornRule} to be viable:
\begin{subequations}
\label{NormalizedKet}
\begin{align}
\sum_{a' \in \mathscr{A}} \braket{\hat{\Lambda}_{a'}}_{\ket{\psi}} = \braket{\smash[b]{\sum_{a' \in \mathscr{A}}} \hat{\Lambda}_{a'}}_{\ket{\psi}} = \braket{\hat{\mathbb{I}}}_{\ket{\psi}} = \bra{\psi} \hat{\mathbb{I}} \ket{\psi} = \braket{\psi \vert \psi} & \mbeq 1 \, , \label{NormalizedKetDiscr} \\
\int\limits_{\mathscr{A}} \! \diff a' \, \braket{\hat{\Lambda}_{a'}}_{\ket{\psi}} = \braket{\smash[b]{\int\limits_{\mathscr{A}}} \! \diff a' \, \hat{\Lambda}_{a'}}_{\ket{\psi}} = \braket{\hat{\mathbb{I}}}_{\ket{\psi}} = \bra{\psi} \hat{\mathbb{I}} \ket{\psi} = \braket{\psi \vert \psi} & \mbeq 1 \, . \label{NormalizedKetCont}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
The (sesqui-)linearity of the inner product \eqref{SesquiLinInnerProd} was used to establish the first equality and the completeness of the set of a self-adjoint operator's eigenkets \eqref{ComplSetKets} for the second. Kets that meet condition \eqref{NormalizedKet} are normalized (to unity).
```

gives the output:
[image]

However, this only happens sometimes. Over the course of me changing something unrelated, equation (1.6) went back to normal behaviour. I've never noticed it for (1.7), but my guess is, it's the same situation there: If some changes on the preceding section changes it to be three lines higher (as a random example) on the page, it's displayed fine again.

Why is that? And how can I fix it?

Due to the mysterious nature of the problem, I haven't put this into a working example because I myself cannot reproduce the error on purpose.

EDIT: The text under 1.7 is followed by a new section. Might be important ..

EDIT II:added preamble in response to Mico's comments

EDIT III: Expansion of the preamble and added a second screenshot of the output after the inclusion of \raggedbottom:

[image]

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Is there a large `align` environment at the start of the next page? If so, what happens if you issue the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks`?

Comment: How or where are `\diff` and `\mbeq` defined?

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a large align environment after some text on the next page.

Where should I issue the \allowdisplaybreaks command? If a want to do it locally, i.e. create a group as outlined here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102174/204015, should that group encompass the large align environment on the next page as well?

Comment: I don't want the command to mess up anything else in the document that I might not immidiately realize. That's why I thought about that option, but I'm new to Latex, so if you tell me that's not necessary because it's harmless, I'm on board :)

Comment: @MarkusGratis Use `\allowdisplaybreaks` only during preparation of the document and remove it when it is in final form, when you can decide with care where to allow breaks with explicit `\displaybreak` directives. You don't want display to be broken in random places.

Comment: The "next page" begins with a new section.  By any chance are you bringing in that section with`\include`?  (That always forces a new page.)

Comment: no, it's because the align environments don't all fit on one page and depending on when the first one starts, this sometimes happens

Comment: I will work this out as the very last thing of my text, so I'll respond and mark the correct answer then

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, there's a sectioning header followed by a long-ish `align` environment at the top of the next page. Moreover, you seem to be unsure as to whether it's a good idea to allow page breaks in `align` and `gather` environments (by making scope of `\allowdisplaybreaks` either global or local.

If you're ok with a page break being inserted *before* that sectioning header, you can afford being a bit more profligate with the spacing in and around the four subequations. E.g., you could (a) replace `\text{and}\quad` in the first `subequation` with `\intertext{and}` and (b) insert an `\intertext{and}` directive between the two parts of the second subequation. Then, insert a `\clearpage` instruction after the end of the final paragraph and keep your fingers crossed that the "hole" at the bottom of the page isn't too prominent. (However, if the "hole" is indeed rather prominent, scratch the `\intertext` idea and go back to experimenting with `\allowdisplaybreaks`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,mathrsfs,amssymb,braket,natbib}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\mbeq}{\overset{!}{=}}
\newcommand\braketI{\braket{\mkern1mu\hat{\mathbb{I}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}  % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{5}

This is known as the \emph{Born rule} or Born's probabilistic interpretation \citep{BornRule}. If two additional observables $ \{ B, C \} $ are necessary to form a CSCO (see \ref{CSCO}), the projector onto the degenerate eigenspace associated with $a'$ is given by:
\begin{subequations}
\label{EigenSpaceProjector}
\begin{align}
\hat{\Lambda}_{a'} & = \smashoperator{%
  \sum_{\substack{i, j \mid b_{i} \in \mathscr{B},\\ 
              \hfill c_{j} \in \mathscr{C}\phantom{,}}}} 
  \,\ket{a', b_{i}, c_{j}} \bra{a', b_{i}, c_{j}} \rightarrow \ket{a'}\bra{a'} \label{EigenSpaceProjectorDiscr} \\
\intertext{and} 
\hat{\Lambda}_{a'} & = \int\limits_{\mathscr{B}} \! \diff b \int\limits_{\mathscr{C}} \! \diff c \, \ket{a', b, c} \bra{a', b, c} \rightarrow \ket{a'} \bra{a'} \, , \label{EigenSpaceProjectorCont}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
with the simpler form included if the eigenvalue $a'$ is non-degenerate. The probability of the measurement returning any value at all has to equal unity in order for the probability interpretation \eqref{BornRule} to be viable:
\begin{subequations}
\label{NormalizedKet}
\begin{align}
\sum_{a' \in \mathscr{A}} \braket{\hat{\Lambda}_{a'}}_{\ket{\psi}} 
&= \Bigl\langle \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a' \in \mathscr{A}}} \hat{\Lambda}_{a'}\!\Bigr\rangle_{\!\ket{\psi}} 
= \braketI_{\ket{\psi}} 
= \bra{\psi} \hat{\mathbb{I}} \ket{\psi} 
= \braket{\psi \vert \psi} \mbeq 1  \label{NormalizedKetDiscr} \\
\intertext{and}
\int\limits_{\mathscr{A}} \! \diff a' \, \braket{\hat{\Lambda}_{a'}}_{\ket{\psi}} 
&= \Bigl\langle \int\limits_{\mathscr{A}} \! \diff a' \, \hat{\Lambda}_{a'}\!\Bigr\rangle_{\!\ket{\psi}} 
= \braketI_{\ket{\psi}} 
= \bra{\psi} \hat{\mathbb{I}} \ket{\psi} 
= \braket{\psi \vert \psi}  \mbeq 1 \, . \label{NormalizedKetCont}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

The (sesqui-)linearity of the inner product \eqref{SesquiLinInnerProd} was used to establish the first equality and the completeness of the set of a self-adjoint operator's eigenkets \eqref{ComplSetKets} for the second. Kets that meet condition \eqref{NormalizedKet} are normalized (to unity).

\clearpage % by all means force a page break here
\end{document}
```