# Too much spacing of the paragraph before a long equation in Align environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I am typing my paper and I get a very awkward page before an  Align environment which contains a long equation (there are too much spacing in the first page, the second page contains only that long equations). Does any one to help me to clear spacing appear in first page?

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,intlimits,oneside]{amsart}

%\usepackage{showkeys}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsthm}showkeys,

\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsthm}



\textwidth14cm \textheight21cm \evensidemargin.2cm
\oddsidemargin.2cm


\begin{document} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{Remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{Example}{Example}[section]

In order to prove the converse of the theorem, we first need the following lemma.
\begin{lemma}\label{mainlem1} Let $w\in {\mathcal W}_\alpha$, $\alpha>-d$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Then the function 
\[
f_{p,\varepsilon}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0\qquad\qquad\quad\;\;\text{if}\quad|x|\leq1&\\
|x|^{-\frac{d+\alpha}p-\varepsilon}\qquad\text{if}\quad|x|\geq1,
\end{cases}
\]
belongs to $L^p_w\left(\mathbb R^d\right)$ and $\|f_{p,\varepsilon}\|_{p,w}=\left(\frac{w(S_d)}{p\varepsilon}\right)^{1/p}$.
\end{lemma}
Since the proof of the lemma is straightforward, we omit it. Now we shall prove the theorem. Let $\varepsilon$ be  an arbitrary positive number and  for each $k=1,\ldots,m$ we set $\varepsilon_k=\frac{p\varepsilon}{p_k}$ and
\[
f_{p_k,\varepsilon_k}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\text{if}\quad|x|\leq1&\\
|x|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\qquad\text{if}\quad|x|\geq1.
\end{cases}
\]
Lemma \ref{mainlem1} implies that $f_{p_k,\varepsilon_k}\in L^{p_k}_{\omega_k}\left(\mathbb R^d\right)$ and 
\[
\|f_{p_k,\varepsilon_k}\|_{p_k,\omega_k}=\left(\frac{\omega_k(S_d)}{p_k\varepsilon_k}\right)^{1/p_k}=\left(\frac{\omega_k(S_d)}{p\varepsilon }\right)^{1/p_k}>0,
\]
for each $k=1,\ldots,m$. For each $x\in\mathbb R^d$ which $|x|\geq1$, let
\begin{align*}
S_x=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^m\{t\in[0,1]^n:\;|s_k(t)x|>1\}.
\end{align*}
From the assumption 
$|s_k(t_1,\ldots,t_n)|\geq \min\{t_1^\beta,\ldots,t_n^\beta\}$ a.e $t=(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\in[0,1]^n$, there exists a null subset $E$ of $[0,1]^n$ so that $S_x$ contains $\left[1/|x|^{1/\beta},1\right]^n\setminus E$. From (\ref{sec2eq1}), we have 
%\leavevmode\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip\relax}
\begin{align*}
\;&\|U^{m,n}_{\psi,\overrightarrow{s}}\left(f_{p_1,\varepsilon_1},\ldots,f_{p_m,\varepsilon_m}\right)\|_{L^p_\omega\left(\mathbb R^d\right)}^p=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\left|\int_{[0,1]^n}\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^mf_k\left(s_k(t)x\right)\right)\psi(t)dt\right|^p\omega(x)dx\\
=\;& \int_{\mathbb R^d}\prod_{k=1}^m|x|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\omega(x)\left|\int_{S_x}\prod_{k=1}^m|s_k(t)|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\psi(t)dt\right|^pdx\\
\geq\;& \int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon^{-\beta}}|x|^{-(d+\alpha+\varepsilon p)}\omega(x)\left|\,\int_{[\varepsilon,1]^n}\prod_{k=1}^m|s_k(t)|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\psi(t)dt\right|^pdx\\
=\;& \varepsilon^{p\beta\varepsilon}\left(\int_{|x|\geq1}|x|^{-(d+\alpha+\varepsilon p)}\omega(x)dx\right)\left|\,\int_{[\varepsilon,1]^n}\prod_{k=1}^m|s_k(t)|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\psi(t)dt\right|^p \\
=\;& \varepsilon^{p\beta\varepsilon}\left(\frac{\omega(S_d)}{\varepsilon p}\right)\left|\,\int_{[\varepsilon,1]^n}\prod_{k=1}^m|s_k(t)|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\psi(t)dt\right|^p \\
\geq\;& \varepsilon^{p\beta\varepsilon}\prod_{k=1}^m\|f_{p_k,\epsilon_k}\|_{p_k,\varepsilon_k}^{p/p_k}\left|\,\int_{[\varepsilon,1]^n}\prod_{k=1}^m|s_k(t)|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\psi(t)dt\right|^p. \\
\end{align*}
This implies that 
\begin{align*}
\left\|U^{m,n}_{\psi,\overrightarrow{s}}\right\|_{L^{p_1}_{\omega_1}\left(\mathbb R^d\right)\times\cdots\times L^{p_m}_{\omega_m}\left(\mathbb R^d\right)\to L^{p}_{\omega}\left(\mathbb R^d\right)}\geq  \varepsilon^{\beta\varepsilon}\cdot\left|\,\int_{[\varepsilon,1]^n}\prod_{k=1}^m|s_k(t)|^{-\frac{d+\alpha_k}{p_k}-\varepsilon_k}\psi(t)dt\right|.
\end{align*} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Is it possible to pagebreak aligned equations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51883)

Comment: You might also want to have a look at `\intertext` and `shortintertext` by (`amsmath` and/or `mathtools`) instead of ending and beginning math environments over and over again.

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you like to answer this one, or close as duplicate?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I was starting to answer, making some imprvements to the code, but on page two i gave up. I voted to close as duplicate.