# hypdvips causing content to overflow into footer

Tags: fancyhdr, dvips, hypdvips

I am having problems with the content of the page running over into the footer. Here is my Minimal Working Example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdvips}

%Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{{\textsc{Some Really Intresting Footer Text}} }
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} % To help see the content overflow into footer

\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox[b][18.8cm][t]{0.33\textwidth}{Some text} }
\[\begin{aligned}
  a =  & \frac{{dv}}{{dt}} \\  
  a =  & \frac{{dv}}{{dt}} \\   
\end{aligned} \]

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `hypdvips` package then it corrects itself. The same goes for when I remove `\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{{\textsc{Some Really Intresting Footer Text}} }`.

Any idea why these three commands are conflicting with each other and how I can get them to work together?

Comment: Removing `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}` doesn't appear to matter. Also, replacing your specific page content with `\lipsum` paragraphs indicates the problem happens due to the inability to page-break an `aligned` environment, as in [Is it possible to pagebreak aligned equations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51682/is-it-possible-to-pagebreak-aligned-equations)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question in regards to `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}`. In this situation I am expecting the entire equation to move to the next page instead of running into the footer.

Comment: If you change `\[` and `\]` to `\begin{gather*}` and `\end{gather*}`, respectively, does the problem go away? What if you set the whole display up with just `align*`? (If you do that, you will of course want to remove the double-backslash after the last line of your display.)