# automatically split \begin{align*} content in two pages

Tags: amsmath

I have a section containing something similar to:

```
\begin{align*}
   ...some long content...
\end{align*}
```

The content is long and should be split in two pages, however, the whole block is moved to the second page leaving an empty space.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it possible to pagebreak aligned equations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51682/5764)

Comment: Have a look for `allowdisplaybreaks` .