# Splitting a matrix into several pages

Tags: page-breaking, matrices

I have some quite long matrices I would like to insert in a LaTeX document, and I wanted to know if it was possible to split the `matrix` environment to allow matrices to be displayed on several pages, as simply reducing enough the font makes my text unreadable. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        0&0\\
        0&0\\
        0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}  
\end{document}
```

In this example, we see that if we remove the last line of zeroes, the matrix will start at page 1 rather than at page 2 as it does here, while if we keep adding lines, LaTeX will continue displaying these additional elements and go beyond margins. I should precise that this is not the matrix I had in mind for my paper.

I should precise that in my specific case, the matrix has enough columns to fill a whole page.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51682/is-it-possible-to-pagebreak-aligned-equations) helps

Comment: Thank you dexteritas. I tried to use the previous answers concerning page breaking of other environments, but my compiler ignored the `\allowdisplaybreaks`and changed pages anyway.

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your problem.

Comment: I assume your actual matrix is not this narrow, otherwise you could fit it one page (albeit in sections).

Comment: @ John Kormylo Indeed, there are actually lengthy coefficient inside the matrix. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is split your huge matrices in submatrices:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{A}_1 \\
\mathbf{A}_2 \\
\mathbf{A}_3 \\
\mathbf{A}_4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\]
where submatrices $\mathbf{A}_1$, $\mathbf{A}_2$, $\mathbf{A}_3$ and $\mathbf{A}_4$ are
\[
\mathbf{A}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\mathbf{A}_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
\quad        
\mathbf{A}_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
\quad        
\mathbf{A}_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        \end{pmatrix}
\] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution if the matrix is narrow enough, but this is not my case, as I precised it in the comments. Please excuse me for being unclear, I will state it explicitly in the question.

Comment: @Paul-Benjamin, I show an example only. This can work even with wide submatrices, for example each on one page.

Answer (score 1):

You could clip it, with a bit of overlap for continuity.  Note that the baseline is at the center (more or less) which corresponds to 0pt in the viewport.  `\strutbox` is a predefined box containing `\strut`, so `\ht\strutbox` is the height of `\strut`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        0&0\\
        0&0\\
        0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0\\
        0&0\\0&0
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*} 
\end{minipage}}%
\adjustbox{clip=true,viewport=0pt {-\ht\strutbox} {\wd\tempbox} {\ht\tempbox}}{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\newpage
\adjustbox{clip=true,viewport=0pt {-\dp\tempbox} {\wd\tempbox} {\dp\strutbox}}{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\end{document}
```

[image: two pages]

Comment: In my editor (TeXstudio) I get a strange result, as the matrix is cut from the middle of the first page. Do you obtain better results on your editor?

Comment: I added an image from my setup (TeXnicCenter, MikTeX and pdflatex).

Comment: Thank you, it does not seem to be the case.