# What to do to have an equation going over the page

Tags: math-mode, page-breaking

I had no idea how to word my question. Sorry for that ! I am working in an 
\align environment. Because my equation is made up of few blocks, Latex creates a page break and starts it on the new page. The image below shows this situation. How can I make him start the equation on page 49 and go over the page to page 50 rather than start on page 50 and leave the massive white gap? I work with wwww.sharelatex.com if that makes any difference.
[image]

EDIT: As Werner suggested adding

\allowdisplaybreaks

fixes the problem.

Comment: You're probably interested in [Is it possible to `\pagebreak` `align`ed equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51682/5764) (possible duplicate). I assume there is more in the align after what we see on p 50? If that's all and you're only using an `equation` environment, there's very little one can do, since `Hence,` and the equation is considered a unit.

Comment: Yes as I said there is a lot more. If there are 3 lines, he does just fine. 4 lines and more he starts to transfer the equation on the next page because I believe he treats it as a unit as you said. Thanks I will have a look on the question you just posted. I just couldn't figure out what keywords to google thats why I created the question.

Comment: Tl;DR: The link suggests adding `\allowdisplaybreaks` to your preamble.

Comment: Yes It worked wonders.  If it is a duplicate feel free to delete the question. Thank you very much!