# split subequations in two pages

Tags: beamer, amsmath, subequations

I have this set of equations that I need to split into two pages. I'm working on beamer. I tried \allowdisplaybreaks but it didn't work:

```
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Problem GENERALMODEL}
  \tiny
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
      \label{generalmodel}
      \underset{\substack{z_v \\ c_{lip}, o_{lip}}}{\text{minimize}} & F(z)\\
      \text{subject to }   & z_v = y \\
      & blah \\
      & blah \\
      & blah \\
      & blah \\
      % Break around here
      & blah \\
      & blah \\
      & blah \\
      & blah \\
      & blah \\
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{frame}
```

Can anyone suggest any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a full working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Maybe related(not beamer): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51883/124842

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]  % <---
\frametitle{Problem GENERAL MODEL}
\Large
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}\label{generalmodel}
  \underset{\substack{z_v \\ c_{lip}, o_{lip}}}{\text{minimize}} & F(z)\\
  \text{subject to }   & z_v = y \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah\ 1i \\
  % Break around here
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah \\
  & blah 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

is this what you looking for?