# Pagebreak multiple (side-by-side) aligned equations inside the equation environment

Tags: equations, page-breaking

I am putting three `\aligned` environments inside an `\equation`, so that they are displayed side by side:

[image: three equations side by side]

However, they have many lines and don't fit to the end of the page, and I am left with a large space at the bottom of the page. It would look much better if there was a page break in-between. I tried using `\allowdisplaybreaks` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51682/is-it-possible-to-pagebreak-aligned-equations), but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to allow page breaks here, while keeping the multiple column structure? This is the code that generates the image above:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% lots of text here

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        V - \frac{mV}{2} + \frac{mV}{n}               = 2                       \\
        V \left( 1 - \frac{m}{2} + \frac{m}{n} \right) = 2                      \\
        V \frac{2n - mn + 2m}{2n}                   = 2                         \\
        V                                             = \frac{4n}{2n - nm + 2m} \\
        V                                             = \frac{4n}{4 - (n-2)(m-2)}
    \end{aligned}
    \hspace{.5em}
    \vline
    \hspace{.5em}
    \begin{aligned}
        \frac{2E}{m} - E + \frac{2E}{n} = 2                \\
        E \left( \frac{2}{m} - 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right) = 2 \\
        E \frac{2n - nm + 2m}{nm} = 2                      \\
        E = \frac{2nm}{2n - nm + 2m}                       \\
        E = \frac{2nm}{4 - (n - 2)(m - 2)}
    \end{aligned}
    \hspace{.5em}
    \vline
    \hspace{.5em}
    \begin{aligned}
        F - \frac{nF}{2} + \frac{nF}{m}               = 2                       \\
        F \left( 1 - \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{m} \right) = 2                      \\
        F \frac{2m - nm + 2n}{2m}                   = 2                         \\
        F                                             = \frac{4m}{2m - mn + 2n} \\
        F                                             = \frac{4m}{4 - (n - 2)(m - 2)}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```