How can a large equation be broken into two pages?
Suppose I have a large block of text now and want to insert a long equation after it, just like in the figure below:

the code is here:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\
dummy text \\

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
    & formula \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

How can I avoid the large blank on the first page? I want the long equation to span across multiple pages.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51682/is-it-possible-to-pagebreak-aligned-equations

use align* not equation and aligned and then \allowdisplaybreaks in the preamble
