# How can I define a macro with literal square brackets in the body?

Tags: math-mode, macros, expansion, brackets

The following macro works correctly for enclosing an expression in parenthesis.

```
\def\group#1{\left ( #1 \right )}
```

I want to write the equivalent macro for enclosing an expression in square brackets. I have tried the following macro with and without backslash-escaping the the square brackets, but both give errors.

```
\def\bgroup#1{\left [ #1 \right ] }
```

How can I define a macro with the desired expansion?

Comment: `\bgroup` is a name used within the LaTeX kernel: did you try with a different name? (`\newcommand` rather than `\def` would tell you this.)

Comment: Oh, I did not try with a different name. Trying that now.

Comment: Changing the name fixed it. That error message was really cryptic! Thank you.

Comment: I could delete the question, but if you want to write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it and we can leave it as a reference in case somebody else happened to use `def` and the name `bgroup` together.

Comment: A few information about `\bgroup`, `\begingroup` and `{`: [When should one use `\begingroup` instead of `\bgroup`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1930)

Comment: @merlin2011 Try doing `\def\fi{whatever}` in the preamble. The error message will be *much* more cryptic. Use `\newcommand` unless you know precisely what you're doing. Redefining “taken” commands is surely possible, but with great care and not just to glob their original meaning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `\bgroup` is used by the LaTeX kernel (and indeed by plain TeX) for low-level operations: as such it is 'reserved'. Thus the problem is not `[` and `]` in the command but rather the choice of `\bgroup` as the name for it. If you use `\newcommand` rather than `\def` you'll see an informative error message indicating that `\bgroup` is 'taken'.