# Koma script: Restore default chapter style

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script

I want to have for just one chapter a special chapter heading format. So I use the command

```
\setkomafont{chapter}{\centering\large\rmfamily}
```

and then I want to revert back to the default chapter style that `scrbook` uses. The problem is that I don't know this default style (e.g. someone may change the preamble and have `\Huge` size instead of `\LARGE` that I have now). Can I somehow save the current chapter style and restore it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the `\setkomafont` and `\chapter` within a group (`{ .. }`), that way the change is local.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This}

{\setkomafont{chapter}{\centering\large\rmfamily}
\chapter{That}}

\chapter{This again}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as a remark: Since simple braces are easy to be overlooked, one could also use `\begingroup … \endgroup`. Related question: [When should one use \begingroup instead of \bgroup?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1930).