# Parsing formatted arguments with expl3

Tags: macros, expl3, subscripts, superscripts

I want to parse subscripts and superspricts using expl3 for which I used `\def` before:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \l__parsing_parse_superscript:n ^#1 {superscript = #1}
\cs_new:Npn \l__parsing_parse_subscript:n _#1 {subscript = #1}
\NewDocumentCommand\parsesuperscript{}{\l__parsing_parse_superscript:n}
\NewDocumentCommand\parsesubscript{}{\l__parsing_parse_subscript:n}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent
\parsesuperscript^10\\
\parsesubscript_100 % TODO error
\end{document}
```

The superscript gets parsed correctly. However for the subscript an error occurs, probably because after `\ExplSyntaxOn` the underscore is treated as a letter. I also tried `\c_underscore_str` and `\c_math_subscript_token` instead of `_` in the command definition. How can the underscore be escaped for parsing a subscript? Or are there other solutions for parsing arguments with expl3 that should be prefered?

References:

- [Defining a newcommand with sub- or superscript and avoiding "double subscript" error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33261/defining-a-newcommand-with-sub-or-superscript-and-avoiding-double-subscript-e)

Comment: It should also be mentioned that commands with nonstandard syntaxes like `<command>^#1` and `<command>_#1` should be denoted `:w` (for “weird”) rather than `:n`.

Comment: @egreg I want do collect multiple subscripts and superscripts like I [commented below the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611751/parsing-formatted-arguments-with-expl3/611754#comment1531502_611754) of Phelype Oleinik. The idea is based on your [solution to avoid "double subscript" errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33261/defining-a-newcommand-with-sub-or-superscript-and-avoiding-double-subscript-e/33263#33263) but extended to allow also superscripts and using expl3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your diagnostics is correct:  the problem is that in `expl3` syntax, the `_` has catcode 11. However using `\c_underscore_str` is no good either because that has catcode 12, but in the document the `_` (usually) has catcode 8.

In your definition you have to enforce catcode 8 for the underscore:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__michael_parse_superscript:w ^#1 {superscript = #1.}
\use:e
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__michael_parse_subscript:w
        \char_generate:nn { `\_ } { 8 } #1
      {subscript = #1.}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\parsesuperscript{}{\__michael_parse_superscript:w}
\NewDocumentCommand\parsesubscript{}{\__michael_parse_subscript:w}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(note also that with `\parsesubscript_100`, only the `1` is grabbed as argument: you need `\parsesubscript_{100}`).

But that's not really parsing, because if you use the command without the following `_` or `^` you'll get an error.  You could use the `e`-type argument instead (note that it works regardless of the order the actual arguments appear):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\NewDocumentCommand \parsesupsub { e{^_} }
  {
    \IfValueT{#1}{superscript = #1.\\}
    \IfValueT{#2}{subscript = #2.\\}
  }
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=10pt
\begin{document}
\parsesupsub^{10}

\parsesupsub_{100}

\parsesupsub_{100}^{10}

\parsesupsub^{10}_{100}
\end{document}
```

You could also parse manually with `\peek_charcode_remove:NTF _ { <with> } { <without> }`, then it would work regardless of the current catcode of `_`.

On naming (I wrote an explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611240/134574)), the `\l_` (or `\g_` or `\c_`) prefix should be used for variables only.  You are defining commands, so they should start with `\module_...` if public, or `\__module_...` if private (I used `michael` as the module name).  Also, as Gaussler noted in the comment, the `:n` argument type should be for "normal" arguments (tokens delimited by `{`...`}`).  Since you have a "weird" token in the parameter text, you should use `:w`.

Comment: @Michael Yes, `\peek_charcode_remove:NTF` is indeed better in this case.  The `e` argument type only takes one argument per token, so `e{^_}` grabs at most two arguments.