# Define new commands which use line-break as delimiter instead of curly braces

Tags: macros, delimiters

I would like to use commands without having curly braces `{}` as delimiters. 
Mostly I would like that the commands work with a line-break as the delimiter.

Herewith a simple example, which does not work (*My* is displayed but missing the line)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\def\chap #1 {\chapter{#1}}
\def\sec #1 {\section{#1}}
\def\subsec #1 {\subsection{#1}}
\def\li #1 {\begin{itemize}\item #1\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
\chap My First Chapter
\sec My First Section
\subsec My First Section
\li lkdsjfaljsfad
\li lkdsjfaljsfad
\li lkdsjfaljsfad
\end{document}
```

Would you know how to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You are aware about the role of `{}` in macro arguments? ;-)

Comment: this just breaks all conventions of latex syntax, you really should not do it:-)  but apart from the syntax don't you want a single list of three items, not three one-item lists?

Comment: not much. Hopefully someone may help me. the above example almost works... but missed the >=2 words until the end of the line (LF)

Comment: Not sure what your actual goal is, but maybe the `markdown` package could be interesting for you

Comment: @debian82933 Usually newbies ask complicated questions for issues, which are easy to solve. So what is your goal?

Comment: the format plain define `\outer\def\beginsection#1\par` and a blanck line is used as delimiter

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191267/command-delimited-by-return-or-blank-line

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a Lua function that operates at a very early stage of processing: it scans all lines of input and simply replaces instances of `\chap .....` with `\chapter{.....}`. (In Lua's `string.gsub` function, the `$` character serves as the end-of-line marker.) Ditto for `\sec ...`, `\subsec ...`, and `\li ...`. With this setup, LaTeX only gets to "see" the standard macros with standard argument formation; no need to define macros called `\chap`, `\sec`, etc.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function scan_ahead ( s )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "\\chap%s+(.*)$" , "\\chapter{%1}" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "\\sec%s+(.*)$" , "\\section{%1}" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "\\subsec%s+(.*)$" , "\\subsection{%1}" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "\\li%s+(.*)$" , "\\begin{itemize}\\item %1\\end{itemize}")
  return s
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer",  scan_ahead , "scan_ahead" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\chap My First Chapter
\sec My First Section
\li lkdsjfaljsfad
\li abc def ghi
\subsec My First Section
\li jkl mno pqr stu
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't use LUATEX, I have only pdflatex  on my system. I cant lua

Comment: @debian82933 - What kind of TeX distribution do you have? Which software do you use for editing (and, presumably, compiling) your tex files?

Comment: Debian with Texlive (small installation), with latex, pdflatex, pdftex and bibtex.

Comment: @debian82933 - Any particular reason for *not* installing LuaTeX and LuaLaTeX as well?

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend this -- it does not look well and breaks the tradition of LaTeX commands.

The code is taken from `egreg`'s answer at [Using end-of-line delimiter in plain Tex macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125549/using-end-of-line-delimiter-in-plain-tex-macro) (upvoted of course ;-))

There's actually nothing to gain from this and distracts from (proof)reading codes.

Especially `\li` is not really useful short version `\item` anyway.

The endline character has usually the catcode 5, so this is converted to a space or `\par` token (depending on the state) first before further processing the input. In order to make `TeX` recognize the end of line the catcode has to be changed, to `12` ('other'), in a group, so use

```
\def\chap{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \xchap}
{\catcode`\^^M=12 %
 \gdef\xchap#1^^M{\chapter{#1}\endgroup}%
}
```

to read the content until the end of the line and let the temporary macro `\xchap` to the display of `\chapter{...}` etc. (the same for `\sec` and `\subsec`.)

Of course, such approaches will break `\chap[foo]{foo bar}`, i.e. the short version of the chapter title meant for `ToC` and page headings are not available any longer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\def\chap{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \xchap}
{\catcode`\^^M=12 %
 \gdef\xchap#1^^M{\chapter{#1}\endgroup}%
}


\def\sec{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \xsec}
{\catcode`\^^M=12 %
 \gdef\xsec#1^^M{\section{#1}\endgroup}%
}

\def\subsec{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \xsubsec}
{\catcode`\^^M=12 %
 \gdef\xsubsec#1^^M{\subsection{#1}\endgroup}%
}



\begin{document}
\chap My First Chapter
\sec My First Section
\subsec My First Section
\begin{itemize}
\item lkdsjfaljsfad
\item lkdsjfaljsfad
\item lkdsjfaljsfad
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

However, this is code golfing, in my point of view.

Comment: the advantage using simple pdflatex is to avoid { } and to make documents clearer and much simpler to type. It is cool and great with \li, \sec, \subsec and it can be simpler to learn.

Comment: @debian82933: No, it isn't. It's pure laziness. In the long end it will bite you

Comment: Lazyness, but rather in first approach for higher  efficiency, rapidity for typing long documents. - why actually?   Commands with line-break delimited is a good, it is like the first discussion from ritchie about // comment delimited by line-break. The use of // with Line-break is still there today in C.  nothing wrong.

Comment: @debian82933: `\chapter{Foo Foobar}` will work for any document class that provides a chapter command, `\chap Foo Foobar` only for documents that have the 'abusive' `\chap` macro -- you have to provide it either with the document itself (blasting up the document size), or write a new class and/or package, let alone that `\chap[foo] Foo bar` won't work any longer

Comment: @debian82933: comparison of `C` and `LaTeX` lead to the wrong end...

Comment: Ok, I am fine, it can be tried. I can try to adapt to LaTeX default standard. I want too really. - But, then, how then can you make LaTeX easily readable and simple to type without having all the time brackets everywhere...?   the example of \section{my chapter} is very complex to write.

Comment: @debian82933: I'm using LaTeX for 20 years now and never complained about using those braces. Just because the syntax of macros is changeable to some extent this does not mean that it is advisable to do so.

Comment: I can understand that you got used to. Wouldn't it be simpler to use \section blabla and give a linebreak. It would be much simpler to type. altgr + { }  is so much keys and long. Furthermore, same story for {\bfseries blabla}, difficult to just bold something, no?

Comment: Use a US - keyboard layout and you don't need `ALTGR` ;-)

Comment: Great ;)  I have a German keyboard, and I can't miss the regular öäü ;)    What about a sort of markup language that would do the job of \sec my-section-name,... ?

Comment: @debian82933: Since you're using Debian you may use a keyboard layout switching command as well -- I have a regular German hardware keyboard, but most times in US software layout to type LaTeX.

Comment: Maybe because Latex over-use the braces, which can make it complex to use. However I agree with you that a line-break shall not be the end of a command, since it is useful to break a long line. In C language, we can do so, which is extremely readable. However, then, how to stop a new command input ?

Comment: @debian82933 - You really ought to reconsider your basic world view, which is (apparently) that "LaTeX over-uses braces". Each programming language has its syntactical requirements; just because you appear to be rather familiar with C doesn't mean that all other programming languages (including TeX) must look behave like C.

Comment: @debian82933 Regarding the typing bit, most LaTeX editors will have some form of autocompletion, which can make it much faster to write code. In TeXworks for example, you can type `s` and then hit the Tab-key, and you'll get `\section{}` with the cursor between the braces.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer (and maybe others): herewith you can find a good workaround for german native speakers, which haven't any easy keyboard. This markup format is a nice workaround to bring an easy typing and it is fairly simple to use, and it is realiable in the time. https://github.com/spartrekus/Unimark

Comment: @debian82933: That's nothing relevant to my answer however -- I don't use markdown  ;-) Add the comment to your question rather