# Three ways of grouping: compare and contrast

Tags: tex-core, grouping

Grouping is often important in TeX/LaTeX programming. I know of three ways to delimit a group:

1. Via a `\begingroup…\endgroup` pair;
2. Via a pair of matched braces `{}`;
3. Via a `\bgroup…\egroup`.

Now I am wondering: what is the difference between these three? Does their effect depend on whether they appear in math mode or text mode? In which way, if so?

**Note:**
I am sure that if I look through the TeXBook, TeX By Topic, and some other resources I will find an answer. However, I am sure there are many others who are curious about this and do not have the time to engage in such a search -- just like me. It would surely be useful to have the info all in one place -- e.g. as an answer here.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/when-should-one-use-begingroup-instead-of-bgroup

Comment: number 3 should be `\bgroup ... \egroup`, not `\endgroup`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton right, fixed.