# Line spacing with line in between

Tags: line-spacing

I would like to make an article that has a line spacing between each line and each space contains a horizontal line. The space needs to be large enough for writing notes by hand. The code below works but obviously this method is very tedious.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{introduction}

X-rays first discovered in 1895 are a form of Electromagnetic radiation 
with\\ 
\vspace{10pt} 
\hline 
\vspace{10pt}
\noindent    
wavelengths of the order of $10^{-10}m$ to simplify this an equivalent unit 
of\\ 
\vspace{10pt}
\hline
\vspace{10pt}
\noindent     
angstrom (A) is used. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses `\vsplit` to pull off one line at a time and reformat it.  The `\parbox` is to restrict where pagebreaks can occur.

Note: `\vspace` doesn't do anything until the end of a line, whereas `\vskip` can only be used in vmode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\myenvbox}

\NewEnviron{myenv}[2]% #1 = distance above line, #2 = distance below line
{\interlinepenalty=-10000
  \setbox\myenvbox=\vbox{\BODY}%
  \noindent
  \loop\ifdim\ht\myenvbox>0pt
    \setbox0=\vsplit\myenvbox to \ht\strutbox
    \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\unvbox0\vskip#1\hrule}\vspace{#2}
  \repeat}

\begin{document}

\section{introduction}

\begin{myenv}{10pt}{10pt}
X-rays first discovered in 1895 are a form of Electromagnetic radiation 
with  
wavelengths of the order of $10^{-10}m$ to simplify this an equivalent unit 
of   
angstrom (A) is used.
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\mysettings{\bgroup%
\parindent=0pt %
\lineskip0pt %
\parskip0pt %
\def\\{\@@par\vspace{10pt}\hrule\vspace{10pt}}}
\makeatother

\def\endmysettings{\egroup}
\begin{document}

\section{introduction}
\begin{mysettings}
X-rays first discovered in 1895 are a form of Electromagnetic radiation 
with\\ 
wavelengths of the order of $10^{-10}m$ to simplify this an equivalent unit 
of\\ 
angstrom (A) is used.\\ 
\lipsum[1]

{\ttfamily\meaning\\}
\end{mysettings}

X-rays first discovered in 1895 are a form of Electromagnetic radiation 
with\\ 
wavelengths of the order of $10^{-10}m$ to simplify this an equivalent unit 
of\\ 
angstrom (A) is used.
{\ttfamily\meaning\\}
\end{document}
```

What I have done is to redefine the `\\` to a simpler form. This is done in a group, so it that it does not interfere with the original definition.

Comment: Excellent solution. But I have some suggestions: (a) Why not use `\newenvironment`; (b) Why not use `\begingroup...\endgroup` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1932/164314))?

Comment: It is simpler and I wrote it this way to make it simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using the `ulem` package. You can define your own *underline* style using, for example, the following command:

```
\newcommand\buline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\rule[-3ex]{.4pt}{.4pt}}\ULon}
```

which can be fine tuned, colored, or replaced by a different line style (dashes, etc.) as required. Also add `\linespread{2.5}` to the preamble to increase line-spacing as needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\linespread{2.5}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\buline{\bgroup\markoverwith{\rule[-3ex]{.4pt}{.4pt}}\ULon}

\section{introduction}

\buline{%
X-rays first discovered in 1895 are a form of Electromagnetic radiation 
with 
wavelengths of the order of $10^{-10}m$ to simplify this an equivalent unit 
of 
angstrom (A) is used.}

\end{document}
```

> [image]