# Lualatex: Arabic in combination with italic - conflict

Tags: arabic

When I try to combine arabic font with italic style I get an error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\begin{document}
    My arabic test
    \arb{With {\itshape some} test}
\end{document}
```

I am aware that the arabic test isn't an arabic test. Nevertheless it works with *`\itshape`*. I am not really sure if the combination makes sense at all. But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_type) suggest it.

Is there a way to get it working in a broader general sense? e.g. Using a different font. Or is it required to adjust it manually case by case?

Plus the other q: Is it possible to combine it with other font styles? e.g. **bold**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting, thank you.

Actually this issue is not related to the font switching commands but to the grouping braces used as delimiters of `\itshape`.

One thing to begin with: no-argument commands should be suffixed with `{}` or "declared" with `\MkArbBreak` before they can be used in Arabic environments.  See [here](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/luatex/latex/arabluatex/arabluatex.pdf#section.11) for more information.

That said, this works:

```
\arb{daxala \bgroup{}\itshape{} 'l-^gAmi`aTa\egroup{} mubtasimaN}

\arb{daxala \bgroup{}\bfseries{} 'l-^gAmi`aTa\egroup{} mubtasimaN}

\arb{daxala \itshape{} 'l-^gAmi`aTa mubtasimaN}

\arb{daxala \bfseries{} 'l-^gAmi`aTa mubtasimaN}
```

etc.

So there is definitely something to be looked into for the next release of `arabluatex`.

It goes without saying that for the time being you should follow Ulrike's sensible advice!

**EDIT:**

Since nesting `\arb{}` into `\arb{}` is allowed, I would recommend to make your inner group like so:---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]

\begin{document}

Without \verb|\MkArbBreak|:

My arabic test
\arb{With \arb{\itshape{} some} test}

My arabic test
\arb{With \arb{\bfseries{} some} test}

With \verb|\MkArbBreak|:

\MkArbBreak*{itshape,bfseries}

My arabic test
\arb{With \arb{\itshape some} test}

My arabic test
\arb{With \arb{\bfseries some} test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stupid q: shouldn't one use `begingroup` instead oft `bgroup`? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1932/48642

Comment: This is not a stupid quetion.  I took `\bgroup` and `\egroup` here for they are defined as `\let\bgroup={` and `\let\egroup=}` respectively.  Therefore they match your example quite well.  That said, there are good reasons to use `\bgroup` in some occasions and `\begingroup` in others.  You can think of `\bgroup`/`\egroup` as "implicit braces".

Answer (score 5):

Use the text variant instead of the font switch. You can declare a different font for it in the fontspec command. Bold seems to work out of the box:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}
 [Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum},
  ItalicFont=Arial,
  ItalicFeatures={Color=red},
 ]
\begin{document}
    My arabic test
    \arb{With \textit{some} \textbf{test} }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx - this helps definitely. It seems like the other font styles work as well out of the box (at least for Italic). The q which arises out of this: Is it more preferable to use the text variant? I guess so but didn't find a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

For me the final solution was with the help of Alessi

```
\arb{daxala \bgroup{}\itshape{} 'l-^gAmi`aTa\egroup{} mubtasimaN}
```

Major reason for this approach is that the translation into TeX happens autoamtically. I need to have a simple approach to use italics in other scenarios as well. Especially for my [other problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532013/48642) with German the approach with `\bgroup` and `\egroup` is brilliant.

The approach from Ulrike seems as well appealing. The major problem I see in the automatic translation of multilines. Therefore I have to refuse it.

Thx **VERY** much to great support here.

Comment: You are welcome.  But have you tried using `csquotes` as Ulrike has suggested there?

Comment: You are really referring to this request? Or to my other? Because here I have no problems with quotes.

Comment: I was referring to this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532013/text-variant-vs-font-switch-bfseries#comment1345167_532013