# Bracing a list within a list

Tags: macros, lists, pgfkeys

I have this set up:

```
%%% some keys
\pgfkeys{/mystuff/first color/.code=\gdef\myfirstcolor{#1}}
\pgfkeys{/mystuff/first color/.default=black}

\pgfkeys{/mystuff/last color/.code=\gdef\mylastcolor{#1}}
\pgfkeys{/mystuff/last color/.default=black}

%%% main cmd
\newcommand{\mylist}[2][]{% aaa [opts] : bbb,...
  \foreach \temp in {#2}{\expandafter\mysplit\temp\relax
  first is \textcolor{\myfirstcolor}{\texttt{\myfirst}},
  last  is \textcolor{\mylastcolor}{\texttt{\mylast}} \par}
}

%%% helper cmds
\def\mysplit#1:#2\relax{%
  \myfirstandopts#1[]\relax%
  \gdef\mylast{#2}
}
\def\myfirstandopts#1[#2]#3\relax{%
  \gdef\myfirst{#1}
  \pgfkeys{/mystuff/.cd,first color,last color,#2}
}
```

The idea is that I give a list and can apply some keys to each of the items:

```
\mylist{Hello:World,
        Hello[first color=blue]:World,
        Hello[last color=red]:World}
```

[image]

If I want to give more than one option, it does not work:

```
\mylist{Hello [first color=blue,last color=red]:World}
! Paragraph ended before \mysplit was complete.
```

The problem is in the foreach.
It gets passed:

```
Hello [first color=blue,last color=red]:World
```

which are two items in the foreach list and the first one,

```
Hello [first color=blue
```

does not agree with the definition.

This is easily solved by bracing the key list:

```
\mylist{Hello[{first color=blue,last color=red}]:World}
```

[image]

However, this is not so intuitive, since normally it is not necessary to brace the whole list of keys.
In this case, it is just because internally it is placed in a list separated with commas.
So, I should like to add the braces automatically.

I have tried to loop over the key list and replace `[` by `[{` and `]` by `}]`.

For this I have used the following macros:

```
\newcount\mycount

\def\mybracedkeys#1{\def\mybrcdkeys{}\myloop#1\relax}%% looping macro by David Carlisle
\def\myloop#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1% check if \relax is reached, if so, do nothing
    \else
      \mycount`#1 % store the ascii code of the character in the counter
      \ifnum\mycount=91% ascii code of [
          \expandafter\def\expandafter\mybrcdkeys\expandafter{\mybrcdkeys [\bgroup}%
        \else
          \ifnum\mycount=93% ascii code of ]
              \expandafter\def\expandafter\mybrcdkeys\expandafter{\mybrcdkeys \egroup]}%
            \else
              \expandafter\def\expandafter\mybrcdkeys\expandafter{\mybrcdkeys #1}
          \fi
      \fi
  \expandafter\myloop\fi}
```

and redefined `\mylist`:

```
\renewcommand{\mylist}[2][]{% aaa [opts] : bbb,...
  \mybracedkeys{#2}
  \foreach \temp in \mybrcdkeys{\expandafter\mysplit\temp\relax
     first is \textcolor{\myfirstcolor}{\texttt{\myfirst}},
     last  is \textcolor{\mylastcolor}{\texttt{\mylast}} \par}
}
```

This still does not work yielding the same error, which is not because we have lost the spaces, since the same happens with:

```
\pgfkeys{/mystuff/.cd,\bgroup first color=blue,last color=red\egroup}
```

I found this explanation by @wipet in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1930/53956):

> The { and } (more exactly the tokens with catcode 1 and 2) have four different meanings in TeX:
>
> - they are the syntactic part of macro definitions: `\def\foo...{...}`
> - each sequence of tokens scanned as single token list in TeX (i.e. in the parameter of a macro, inside macro definitions...) have to be balanced text by these tokens: `\macro{param{e}ter}.`
> - they are a part of several TeX primitive constructions, for example `\hbox...{...}, $e^{...}$, \write...{...}`.
> - when they are used without any context mentioned above they open and close the group.

> The `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are declared by `\let\bgroup={ \let\egroup=}` and you can replace `{` and `}` by `\bgroup` and `\egroup` only in the third and fourth meaning mentioned above.

I guess that in this case we are in the second meaning so it can not be done.

Is there some other way to get it working?
Preferably without `expl3`.
Although, after so many complications (and the spaces issue has not yet been addressed), having to brace the key list does not seem so bad.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section*{Bracing a list within a list}

%%% some keys
\pgfkeys{/mystuff/first color/.code=\gdef\myfirstcolor{#1}}
\pgfkeys{/mystuff/first color/.default=black}

\pgfkeys{/mystuff/last color/.code=\gdef\mylastcolor{#1}}
\pgfkeys{/mystuff/last color/.default=black}

%%% main cmd
\newcommand{\mylist}[2][]{% aaa [opts] : bbb,...
  \foreach \temp in {#2}{\expandafter\mysplit\temp\relax
  first is \textcolor{\myfirstcolor}{\texttt{\myfirst}},
  last  is \textcolor{\mylastcolor}{\texttt{\mylast}} \par}
}

%%% helper cmds
\def\mysplit#1:#2\relax{%
  \myfirstandopts#1[]\relax%
  \gdef\mylast{#2}
}

\def\myfirstandopts#1[#2]#3\relax{%
  \gdef\myfirst{#1}
  \pgfkeys{/mystuff/.cd,first color,last color,#2}
}

\begin{verbatim}
\mylist{Hello:World,
        Hello[first color=blue]:World,
        Hello[last color=red]:World}
\end{verbatim}

\mylist{Hello:World,
        Hello[first color=blue]:World,
        Hello[last color=red]:World}

 \begin{verbatim}
 \mylist{Hello[{first color=blue,last color=red}]:World}
 \end{verbatim}
 
 \mylist{Hello[{first color=blue,last color=red}]:World}
 
 \newcount\mycount
  
 \def\mybracedkeys#1{\def\mybrcdkeys{}\myloop#1\relax}%% looping macro by David Carlisle
 \def\myloop#1{%
    \ifx\relax#1% check if \relax is reached, if so, do nothing
       \else
         \mycount`#1 % store the ascii code of the character in the counter
          \ifnum\mycount=91% ascii code of [
              \expandafter\def\expandafter\mybrcdkeys\expandafter{\mybrcdkeys [\bgroup}%
            \else
              \ifnum\mycount=93% ascii code of ]
                   \expandafter\def\expandafter\mybrcdkeys\expandafter{\mybrcdkeys \egroup]}%
                \else
                   \expandafter\def\expandafter\mybrcdkeys\expandafter{\mybrcdkeys #1}
          \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\myloop\fi}
 
 \renewcommand{\mylist}[2][]{% aaa [opts] : bbb,...
   \mybracedkeys{#2}
   \foreach \temp in \mybrcdkeys{\expandafter\mysplit\temp\relax
     first is \textcolor{\myfirstcolor}{\texttt{\myfirst}},
     last  is \textcolor{\mylastcolor}{\texttt{\mylast}} \par}
 }
 
  does not work
 
\verb|\mylist{Hello[first color=blue,last color=red]:World}|
 
does not work

\verb|\pgfkeys{/mystuff/.cd,\bgroup first color=blue,last color=red\egroup}|


%https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1930/53956


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I mean that you want to protect brackets `[...]` by `[{...}]` and then run your `\foreach`. Rename your `\mylist` macro to `\mylistA` and define

```
\def\mylist#1{%
  \edef\tmp{\protectbk#1[\end]}%
  \expandafter\mylistA\expandafter{\tmp}%
}
\def\protectbk#1[#2]{#1\ifx\end#2\else[{#2}]\expandafter\protectbk\fi}
```

Now, the usage of:

```
\mylist{Hello [first color=blue,last color=red]:World}
```

does

```
\mylistA{Hello [{first color=blue,last color=red}]:World}
```

Comment: That works nicely. Would it be possible to do it without `\edef`? There could be keys like `text=\textbf{some text}`.

Comment: Try this: `\protected \expandafter\def \expandafter\textbf \expandafter{\csname textbf \endcsname}`. We are using this: 1. `\protected\def` macros are not expanded during `\edef`. 2. LaTeX defines its internal `\textbf` as `\textbf space`.